# Runtime error 13 - Mismatch on select files, not all

Tags: vba, type-mismatch

I have a headscratcher here.  Quick background, I "inherited" a pretty complex (to my standards) macro  (see attached code, this is just a piece of it!) and I'm encountering an issue where, some files return a "13 mismatch."  when I go into debug mode it highlights the following portion of the script:

**Quantity = LineSplit(NumCPUPos)**  <- located around line 130 assuming the formatting stayed the same

The interesting thing is that this doesn't happen to other files where the data is roughly the same (only the numbers are different).  Even more interesting, if I take the file that gave me this debug error and just copy->paste the information back *into the same file* and save it...then the macro will run without any errors.

Any thoughts on A) why? and B) how to fix?

````
Sub ProcessHostExport(ByVal file As String)
    Dim line As String
    Dim LineCount As Double
    Dim LineSplit As Variant
    Dim hostPos As Integer, UsagePos As Integer, productPos As Integer, LicensePos As Integer, CenterPos As Integer
    Dim NumCPUPos As Integer, keyPos As Integer, metricPos As Integer, clusterPos As Integer, NumCorePos As Integer, vmPos As Integer
    Dim Host As String, Usage As Variant, Product As String, License As String, Center As String
    Dim Quantity As Integer, Metric As String, Cluster As String, Key As String, NumCPU As Integer, NumCore As Integer, VM As Integer
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim Matches As Object
    
    ' Reset the flags
    VI3Flag = False
    MetricFlag = False
    MissingFlag = False
    DupeFlag = False
    
    ' Setup RegEx
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Pattern = "(""[^""]*"")|([^,]*)"
    RegEx.Global = True
    
    ' Open file as line input and loop through lines
    Open file For Input As #2
    LineCount = 0
    Do Until EOF(2)
        ' Read line
        LineCount = LineCount + 1
        Line Input #2, line
        
        ' Check for empty row or if row starts with non-alphanumeric characters
        If Trim(line) = "" Then Exit Do
        
        ' Replace tabs with commas in the line if needed
        If InStr(1, line, Chr(9)) <> 0 Then line = Replace(line, Chr(9), ",")
        
        ' Correct headers
        If LineCount = 1 Then
            If InStr(1, UCase(line), "SERVER SYSTEM") <> 0 Then line = Replace(UCase(line), "SERVER SYSTEM", "SERVER")
            If InStr(1, UCase(line), "ASSET") <> 0 Then line = Replace(UCase(line), "ASSET", "HOST")
            If InStr(1, UCase(line), "NAME") <> 0 Then line = Replace(UCase(line), "NAME", "HOST")
            If InStr(1, UCase(line), "LICENSEKEY") <> 0 Then line = Replace(UCase(line), "LICENSEKEY", "LICENSE KEY")
        End If
        
        ' Split the line to an array
        LineSplit = Split(line, ",")
        If UBound(LineSplit) >= 2 Then
            
            ' If the line is the header
            If LineCount = 1 Then
                ' Verify that file is a csv
                If UBound(LineSplit) = 0 Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Log").Cells(logRow, 3) = "ERROR: Records are not comma separated"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Log").Cells(logRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
                
                ' Check for non-alphanumeric characters at the beginning of the file
                Do While InStr(1, ALLCHARS, Left(line, 1)) = 0
                    line = Right(line, Len(line) - 1)
                Loop
                
                ' Remove double quotes around entries
                line = Replace(line, Chr(34), "")
                
                ' Get header positions
                hostPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "HOST")
                productPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "PRODUCT")
                UsagePos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "USAGE")
                NumCPUPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "NUMCPU")
                keyPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "LICENSE KEY")
                LicensePos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "LICENSE")
                ServerPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "SERVER")
                metricPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "METRIC")
                clusterPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "CLUSTER")
                NumCorePos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "NUMCORES")
                vmPos = GetHeaderPosition(line, "VMCOUNT")
                
                ' Check that the required headers are available
                If hostPos = -1 Or productPos = -1 Or (UsagePos = -1 And NumCPUPos = -1) Or (keyPos = -1 And LicensePos = -1) Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Log").Cells(logRow + 1, 3) = "ERROR: Required column header missing"
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Log").Cells(logRow + 1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Exit Do
                End If
                
                If ServerPos= -1 Then ServerPos = Right(file, Len(file) - InStrRev(file, "\"))
                
            Else
                ' Check for and correct values with commas and double quotes
                If InStr(1, line, Chr(34)) > 0 Then
                    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(line)
                    
                    LineSplit(hostPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(hostPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    LineSplit(productPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(productPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    
                    If UsagePos <> -1 Then LineSplit(UsagePos) = Replace(Matches.Item(UsagePos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If NumCPUPos <> -1 Then LineSplit(NumCPUPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(NumCPUPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If keyPos <> -1 Then LineSplit(keyPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(keyPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If LicensePos <> -1 Then LineSplit(LicensePos) = Replace(Matches.Item(LicensePos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If ServerPos<> -1 Then LineSplit(ServerPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(ServerPos* 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If metricPos <> -1 Then LineSplit(metricPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(metricPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If clusterPos <> -1 Then LineSplit(clusterPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(clusterPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If NumCorePos <> -1 Then LineSplit(NumCorePos) = Replace(Matches.Item(NumCorePos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                    If vmPos <> -1 Then LineSplit(vmPos) = Replace(Matches.Item(vmPos * 2).Value, Chr(34), "")
                End If
                
                ' Get the deployment details
                Host = LineSplit(hostPos)
                
                Product = NormalizeProduct(LineSplit(productPos))
                If InStr(1, Product, "VI3") <> 0 Then
                    VI3Flag = True
                End If
                
                If UsagePos <> -1 Then
                    If InStr(1, LineSplit(UsagePos), " ") <> 0 Then
                        Usage = Split(LineSplit(UsagePos), " ")
                        Quantity = Usage(0)
                        Metric = Usage(1)
                    Else
                        If LineSplit(UsagePos) = "" Then
                            Quantity = 0
                        Else
                            Quantity = LineSplit(UsagePos)
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    Quantity = LineSplit(NumCPUPos)
                End If
                
                If keyPos <> -1 Then Key = LineSplit(keyPos)
                If LicensePos <> -1 Then License = LineSplit(LicensePos)
                If ServerPos<> -1 Then vCenter = LineSplit(ServerPos)
                
                If metricPos <> -1 Then Metric = LineSplit(metricPos)
                Select Case Metric
                    Case "server"
                        Metric = "Instance"
                    Case "cpuPackage"
                        Metric = "CPUs"
                    Case "vm"
                        Metric = "VMs"
                        If vmPos <> -1 Then Quantity = LineSplit(vmPos)
                    Case ""
                        Metric = "Check Quantity and Metric"
                        MetricFlag = True
                    Case Else
                        ' Do nothing
                End Select
                
                If clusterPos <> -1 Then Cluster = LineSplit(clusterPos)
                If NumCorePos <> -1 And NumCPUPos <> -1 Then NumCore = LineSplit(NumCorePos) / LineSplit(NumCPUPos)
                
                If keyPos <> -1 Then
                    AddDeployment Key, Host, Product, Quantity, Key, License, vCenter, Metric, Cluster, NumCore, False
                Else
                    AddDeployment License & Product, Host, Product, Quantity, "", License, vCenter, Metric, Cluster, NumCore, False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    
    ' Update the file log
    Add2Log file, "Hosts"
    
    Close #2
    
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Likely `LineSplit(NumCPUPos)` isn't an `Integer` (or coercible to one).

Comment: if copying solves the problem it is most likely a data quality issue of the according file and not of the code - except that the code does not handle incompatible formats

Comment: @Ike that's what I'm thinking...the issue I'm encountering IRL is that this customer has 2 host environments, both ran the same tool and provided the same (in theory) output and yet only 1 went through correctly while the other debug'd.  I also validated the process to make sure there wasn't any accidental "fat fingering" and there wasn't.

Comment: @BigBen wouldn't  "Dim LineSplit As Variant" fix that or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps, might break elsewhere. Did it error out when you tried it?